# Problem with showing properties of linear transformation

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $F:K^3\rightarrow K^3$ be a linear transformation, such that

1. $(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)\neq0,$
2. $(F-\mu I)^2\neq 0,$
3. $(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)^2=0.$

With this knowledge I want to show that

1. $\lambda$, $\mu$ are eigenvalues of $F$,
2. $Ker (F-\mu I)\subseteq Im(F-\mu I)$,
3. $F$ has in a certain basis matrix
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \lambda & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & \mu & 1  \\
   0  & 0 &\mu
   \end{pmatrix}.
   \end{equation*}

My attempt:

1. It seems to be a consequence of the third assumption, but I am not sure.
2. We know that $Ker(F-\mu I)=\{v\in K^3:F(v)-\mu v=0\}$ and $Im(F-\mu I)=\{(F-\mu I)(v):v\in K^3\}=\{(F(v)-\mu v):v\in K^3\}$. Then the inclusion seems to be trivial, but I am also not sure.
3. Unfortunately I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: Why do you use the non-classical name "transition" instead of "transformation" ?

Comment: I got used to this name. Anyway, I'll edit it.

Comment: What about the transformation $v\mapsto\lambda v$ for all $v\in K^3$ with $\lambda\neq\mu$? It satisfies all the conditions, but its only eigenvalue is $\lambda$.

Comment: @Vercassibelaunos unfortunately I don't understand your advice.

Comment: @Novice He is telling you that the statements that you want to show are incorrect. The transformation he describes is a counterexample.

Comment: I have done some typos. Maybe now situation is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $\lambda\neq \mu$.

Note that the factors $F-k I$ commute for all $k$.

1. Let $v$ be a vector $v\in K^3$ such that $(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)\,v=u\neq 0$. Then:
   $$
   (F-\mu I)\,u=(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)^2\,v=0
   $$
   so $u$ is an eigenvector for $\mu$.

Analogously, let $w$ be a vector $w\in K^3$ such that $(F-\mu I)^2\,w=z\neq 0$. Then:
$$
(F-\lambda I)\,z=(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)^2\,w=0
$$
so $z$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$.

2. In part 3. we can see that the dimension of $Ker(F-\mu I)$ is 1, otherwise $F$ would be diagonalizable. So $u\in Ker(F-\mu I)$ from previous point is a basis of $Ker(F-\mu I)$. But $u=(F-\mu I)v'$ where $v'=(F-\lambda I)v$ thus $u\in Im(F-\mu I)$.

NOTE: I do not like this proof because it uses part 3. but right now I cannot think of something easier.

3. The polynomial $(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)^2$ from statement 3 is the characteristic polynomial, because it has degree three, and it does not vanish when removing any of its factors. Thus $\mu$ has multiplicity 2 and the diagonal of the Jordan form of $F$ is $(\lambda,\mu,\mu)^\top$. But if $F$ were diagonalizable, then $(F-\lambda I)(F-\mu I)=0$, which is in contradiction with statement 1.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. Can I ask why _$dimKer(F−μI)$ is 1, otherwise $F$ would be diagonalizable_?  $F$ would be diagonalizable if $dimKer(F−μI)=2$ in our case?

Comment: If there is a basis of eigenvectors, then $F$ is diagonal when expressed in that basis. To be an eigenvector corresponding to $\mu$ is equivalent to belonging to $Ker(F-\mu I) $.